# Hour picker html5 in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to do, with no jQuery, something like:

```
<input type="date"/>
```

that opens a select date in textbox but for time picker? I just can't figure it out a way.

It is exactly what this input does, but with hours and minutes, not with days, months, years.

Comment: `<input type="time" />` ?

Comment: You can do 2 separate dropdown inputs​, one for hour and one for minutes...(and​ one for am/pm?)

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'time' input type but it does not have much browser support at the moment.

From w3schools example

```html
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      Select a time:
      <input type="time" name="usr_time">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

will be received as military time

Comment: First, many thanks! :) Second, jquery ui datePicket has more support?

Comment: Depending on your needs it may be better to use a lib. Something like http://timepicker.co/

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look!